# SonarCloud issue when we use azure devops with self hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, sonarcloud

SonarCloud server [https://sonarcloud.io] can not be reached

```
at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:179)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:193)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1670)
```

Comment: It sounds like an SSL networking problem. Are you behind a firewall or any other network packages inspector?

Comment: There is not behind a firewall. when I curl the same URL(https://sonarcloud.io) from agent getting a successful response. When I run pipeline it is throwing that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tested a sonar scanning example with self-hosted agent, on my side, everything works well.

[image]
[image]

You can check and verify SonarCloud service connection in Service connections in Project Settings.

[image]

In addition , you can follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/labs/devops/sonarcloudlab/) about integrating SonarCloud with Azure Devops.

Comment: Sonar scanner is configured properly because when we try with azure hosted machine it is working fine. Mine is PHP project so we should use a standalone scanner. Is it working for you with a stand-alone scanner?